# Html file automatic website login

Tags: html, authentication, web

I was wondering if anyone know if it is possible to have a html file on your desktop that when you click it opens a website and are automaticly logged in. The website im wondering about is www.zarpgaming.com. If anyone know how or if its possible I would really appreciate the help

Best wishes Josh

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script to automatically log you in, and there is many chrome extensions (not to mention built in browser functionality) that can do this.